# How can I keep the authenticated user's uploaded image remain displayed even when refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I've successfully managed to display (in the `<Gallery/>` component) and store the user uploaded AWS S3 URL photos in the DB while the user's authenticated.

However, upon refreshing the page - I'd like the following to happen.  Let's user person `A` and person `B` as exmples.

1. Keep that image on the page while user `A` is logged in even though they refreshed the page
2. If user `A` logs out and user `B` decides to login - user `B` should be able to see user `A`'s upload, and vice versa.

In the `<Gallery/>` component, I'm trying to check if the user's authenticated hoping that this would do what I want it to (have the image remain displayed despite refreshing the page) - but it doesn't work.

Note: The `<Grid/>` component's responsible for displaying the user's uploaded photo.

I've made it this far and been stuck on this for a while now.  I've tried looking online but all the answers I've come across seem vague.  Any help/tips/feedback/improvements would be highly appreciated :).

Here's `App.js`:

```
function App() {

let history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (authToken !== null) {
        console.log(authToken, "User's authenticated, returning to Gallery view");
        return history.push('/gallery');
    }
    console.log("User's authenticated, returning to login view");
    return history.push('/');
});

return (
    <>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginSignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery}/>
        </Switch>
    </>
);
```

}

Here's `Gallery.js`:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import '../../../sass/Gallery/Gallery.scss';
import Grid from "../Grid/Grid";
import { Button, Modal, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const S3_BUCKET = 'my/assets/for/my/site/path';
const REGION = 'us-east-2';

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'myAccessId',
    secretAccessKey: 'mySecretAccessKey'
});

const myBucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {Bucket: S3_BUCKET},
    region: REGION,
});

const Gallery = () => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

    // File Upload
    const [filePreview, setFilePreview] = useState(null);
    const [chosenImage, setChosenImage] = useState(false);
    const [userUploadedImg, setUserUploadedImg] = useState('');
    const [userEmail, getUserEmail] = useState('');
    const [userName, getUserName] = useState('');
    const [userId, getUserId] = useState('');
    const [userAuthtoken, getUserAuthToken] = useState('');

    // Preview modal
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const handleFileInput = (e) => {
        setFilePreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserName(Cookies.get('name'));
        getUserEmail(Cookies.get('email'));
        getUserId(Cookies.get('UserID'));
        getUserAuthToken(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    });

    const uploadFile = (file) => {
        const params = {
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Body: file,
            Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
            Key: file.name,
            ContentType: 'image/jpg'
        };

        let img = myBucket.endpoint.protocol + '//' + myBucket.endpoint.host + "/" + params.Bucket + "/" + params.Body.name;
        console.log(img);
        setUserUploadedImg(img);
        setChosenImage(true);
        console.log(userEmail, userName, userUploadedImg, userId);

        const data = {
            'email': userEmail,
            'name': userName,
            'photoUrl': img,
            'likes': 1,
            'UserID': userId
        }

        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${userAuthtoken}`
        }

        JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(data);

        axios.post('http://mySite.test/api/photos', data, {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

        myBucket.putObject(params)
            .on('httpUploadProgress', (evt) => {
                setProgress(Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100));
            })
            .send((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("yo");
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="fileUpload text-center">
                <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInput}/>
                {/*<button onClick={() => uploadFile(selectedFile)}>Upload to S3</button>*/}
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                    Launch demo modal
                </Button>
            </div>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <h1>Would you like to upload this photo?</h1>
                <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {filePreview && <Image src={filePreview} fluid/>}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => uploadFile(selectedFile)}>Upload!</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>

            {

                (filePreview && chosenImage) ?
                    <>
                        {userAuthtoken ? <Grid imgSrc={filePreview} userName={userName}/> : <h1>no auth token</h1>}
                    </>
                    : <h1>no photos</h1>
            }
        </>
    );
}


export default Gallery;
```

Comment: React will lose its state on refresh. Why not persist the image url in `localStorage` and modify your logic accordingly?

Comment: Also, any reason you want to run your `useEffect` on every render? Instead just one time? It's just extracting cookie info. (I am on the phone so I have only skimmed the code)

Comment: @ManpreetKrishan you're right - I tried to extract cookie info inside `uploadFile()` method upon user uploading a photo, but the response would return empty strings.  In `useEffect`, it's not returning an empty response.

Comment: Consider adding an empty array `[]` as second argument to `useEffect` so that it only runs once when the component mounts and not every time it re-renders.